# How to override line numbering for displaying codes in verbatim package

Tags: numbering, verbatim, code

I have a code block that I want to display in latex using verbatim package but  I would like to custom number the code lines rather than having them start from 1. Here's the example of the latex code I am concerned about:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,xleftmargin=5mm]

    //Initial matrix alignment for A and B
        int shift_source, shift_destination;
        MPI_Cart_shift(row_communicator, 0, -coordinates[0], &shift_source, &shift_destination);
        MPI_Sendrecv_replace(A_local_block, A_local_block_size, MPI_DOUBLE,                                                      shift_destination, 0, 
                 shift_source, 0, row_communicator, &status);

        MPI_Cart_shift(column_communicator, 0, -coordinates[1], &shift_source, &shift_destination);
        MPI_Sendrecv_replace(B_local_block, B_local_block_size, MPI_DOUBLE, 
                 shift_destination, 0, 
                 shift_source, 0, column_communicator, &status);

    // cannon's algorithm
    .
    .
    .
    .
    MPI_Finalize();
}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Here's how it looks after compilation :
[image]

I would want to start the verbatim package to start numbering the lines starting from say 200 rather than 1.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Your code was not compilable. I added `\documentclass` and `\end{Verbatim}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the `firstnumber` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,xleftmargin=5mm,firstnumber=200]

    //Initial matrix alignment for A and B
        int shift_source, shift_destination;
        MPI_Cart_shift(row_communicator, 0, -coordinates[0], &shift_source, &shift_destination);
        MPI_Sendrecv_replace(A_local_block, A_local_block_size, MPI_DOUBLE,                                                      shift_destination, 0, 
                 shift_source, 0, row_communicator, &status);

        MPI_Cart_shift(column_communicator, 0, -coordinates[1], &shift_source, &shift_destination);
        MPI_Sendrecv_replace(B_local_block, B_local_block_size, MPI_DOUBLE, 
                 shift_destination, 0, 
                 shift_source, 0, column_communicator, &status);

    // cannon's algorithm
    .
    .
    .
    .
    MPI_Finalize();
}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative with `verbatimbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbbox}[{\rmfamily\tiny\the\numexpr200+\value{VerbboxLineNo}\relax}\quad\scriptsize]
    //Initial matrix alignment for A and B
        int shift_source, shift_destination;
        MPI_Cart_shift(row_communicator, 0, -coordinates[0], &shift_source, &shift_destination);
        MPI_Sendrecv_replace(A_local_block, A_local_block_size, MPI_DOUBLE,                                                      shift_destination, 0, 
                 shift_source, 0, row_communicator, &status);

        MPI_Cart_shift(column_communicator, 0, -coordinates[1], &shift_source, &shift_destination);
        MPI_Sendrecv_replace(B_local_block, B_local_block_size, MPI_DOUBLE, 
                 shift_destination, 0, 
                 shift_source, 0, column_communicator, &status);

    // cannon's algorithm
    .
    .
    .
    .
    MPI_Finalize();
}
\end{verbbox}
\hspace{5mm}\theverbbox
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hey Steven. thanks a lot for the helpful suggestion.